# change keeplived process user from root to keepalived(or other)

Tags: linux, permissions, suse, keepalive

**I want to know how to change the process name root to another one?**

when using the following command:

```
ps aux | grep keepalived
```

```
root     26982  0.0  0.0  19344  1560 ?        Ss   11:52   0:00 /usr/local/keepalived-2.0.16/sbin/keepalived -D
root     26983  0.0  0.1  19344  2404 ?        S    11:52   0:02 /usr/local/keepalived-2.0.16/sbin/keepalived -D
root     30816  0.0  0.0   9288  1628 pts/1    S+   13:49   0:00 grep --color=auto keepalived
```

keepalived working as expected handle virtual IP and failover.

**but I want to change root to username:keepalived**

**my env:**

- linux distribution:SUSE SLES 12 SP4
- linux kernel:4.12.14-95.13
- Unix daemon:systemd
- keepalived version:

  - 1.4.5(use zypper from https://software.opensuse.org/package/keepalived)
  - also, try to make install from source code
  - follow the install step from https://www.keepalived.org/doc/installing_keepalived.html#build-and-install
  - 1.4.5(from https://www.keepalived.org/download.html)
  - 2.0.16(from https://www.keepalived.org/download.html)

(due to https://www.keepalived.org/index.html says:"*Keepalived code present in git master branch must be considered as stable and futur proof.*",

and https://www.keepalived.org/manpage.html only show one version(is that 2.0.16?) document, I choose 2.0.16 to discuss)

(the following information is 2.0.16 version, Run command as root, but I can see the similar error in 1.4.5)

***how I install keepalived:***

```
wget http://keepalived.org/software/keepalived-2.0.16.tar.gz
tar -xvf keepalived-2.0.16.tar.gz
cd keepalived-2.0.16/
zypper in gcc
zypper in openssl-devel
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/keepalived-2.0.16
make
sudo make install
```

***setting keepalived.conf***

```
vi /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf
```

```
! Configuration File for keepalived
global_defs {
    script_user keepalived
    enable_script_security
}
# Script used to check if nginx is running
vrrp_script check_nginx {
    script "/etc/keepalived/check_nginx.sh"
    interval 2
    weight 2
}
# Virtual interface
# The priority specifies the order in which the assigned interface to take over in a failover
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 150
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass pass
    }
    # The virtual ip address shared between the two loadbalancers
    virtual_ipaddress { # Block limited to 20 IP addresses
        192.168.2.179
    }
    track_script {
        check_nginx
    }
}
```

**what I already try:**

1. cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/keeplaived.service to  /etc/systemd/system/keepalived.service and add user tag

```
User=keepalived
Group=users
```

**but keepalived not working anymore, keepalived stop.**

2. change dir, permission in /etc/systemd/system/keepalived.service

```
#PIDFile=/var/run/keepalived.pid
ExecStart=/usr/local/keepalived-2.0.16/sbin/keepalived $KEEPALIVED_OPTIONS -p /etc/keepalived/keepalived.pid -r /etc/keepalived/vrrp.pid -c /etc/keepalived/keepalived_checkers.pid
```

```
useradd -M -s /bin/nologin -d /opt/keepalived keepalived
```

```
chown -R keepalived:users /etc/keepalived/
```

**this time keepalived start working**

```
keepali+ 26289  0.0  0.0  19344  1628 ?        Ss   11:34   0:00 /usr/local/keepalived-2.0.16/sbin/keepalived -D -p /etc/keepalived/keepalived.pid -r /etc/keepalived/vrrp.pid -c /etc/keepalived/keepalived_checkers.pid
keepali+ 26290  0.0  0.1  19344  2456 ?        S    11:34   0:00 /usr/local/keepalived-2.0.16/sbin/keepalived -D -p /etc/keepalived/keepalived.pid -r /etc/keepalived/vrrp.pid -c /etc/keepalived/keepalived_checkers.pid
root     26323  0.0  0.0   9288  1628 pts/1    S+   11:35   0:00 grep --color=auto keepalived
```

**but got following error in systemctl status keepalived and journalctl -xe**

```
-- Unit keepalived.service has begun starting up.
Keepalived[10409]: Starting Keepalived v2.0.16 (05/03,2019), git commit v2.0.15-96-g4d492740+
Keepalived[10409]: Running on Linux 4.12.14-95.13-default #1 SMP Fri Mar 22 06:04:58 UTC 2019 (c01bf34) (bu
Keepalived[10409]: Command line: '/usr/local/keepalived-2.0.16/sbin/keepalived' '-D' '-p'
Keepalived[10409]:               '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.pid' '-r' '/etc/keepalived/vrrp.pid' '-c'
Keepalived[10409]:               '/etc/keepalived/keepalived_checkers.pid'
Keepalived[10409]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Keepalived[10409]: Failed to bind to process monitoring socket - errno 1 - Operation not permitted
systemd[1]: Started LVS and VRRP High Availability Monitor.
-- Subject: Unit keepalived.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit keepalived.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Keepalived[10409]: Remove a zombie pid file /etc/keepalived/keepalived.pid
Keepalived[10409]: Remove a zombie pid file /etc/keepalived/vrrp.pid
Keepalived[10412]: Starting VRRP child process, pid=10413
Keepalived_vrrp[10413]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
Keepalived_vrrp[10413]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
Keepalived_vrrp[10413]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Keepalived_vrrp[10413]: Assigned address 192.168.2.178 for interface eth0
Keepalived_vrrp[10413]: Assigned address fe80::a00:27ff:feef:6ebe for interface eth0
Keepalived_vrrp[10413]: Error 1 while registering gratuitous ARP shared channel
Keepalived_vrrp[10413]: (VI_1) removing VIPs.
Keepalived_vrrp[10413]: Netlink: error: Operation not permitted, type=RTM_DELADDR(21), seq=1557728895, pid=
Keepalived_vrrp[10413]: cant open raw socket. errno=1
Keepalived_vrrp[10413]: (VI_1) Entering BACKUP STATE (init)
Keepalived_vrrp[10413]: VRRP sockpool: [ifindex(2), family(IPv4), proto(112), unicast(0), fd(-1,-1)]
Keepalived_vrrp[10414]: Couldn't setgroups: 100 (Operation not permitted)
Keepalived_vrrp[10413]: VRRP_Script(check_nginx) succeeded
Keepalived_vrrp[10413]: (VI_1) Changing effective priority from 150 to 152
Keepalived_vrrp[10415]: Couldn't setgroups: 100 (Operation not permitted)
```

(in my case, I use keepalived to failover the nginx )
also, I want to ask

- is there a forum or Q&A for keepalived?
- the better way to install keepalived?

  - keepalived 1.4.5(for now) from zypper(package manager)?
  - keepalived latest 2.0.16(for now) from source code?
- is something I do or what I think is wrong or weird?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According to the response by Alexandre Cassen(I asked with email)
> ....
>
> The answer is quite simple, in fact due to the fact Keepalived is
> operating at OS level, it will not work if run with another user with
> less privileges than root. Keepalived need to open differents routing
> channel and system with kernel that can only be done with root level
> auth (RAW socket, netlink setting channel, ...).
>
> Quickly reading your post on that forum and just to confirm, Last
> stable release on Keepalived website must be considered for
> production. I am really upset that most of linux distro are sill
> shipping very old release. Canonical/Ubuntu made an advance on the
> topic and we created a [snapcraft.io](https://snapcraft.io) package for Keepalived is closely
> linked to Keepalived github. But using that last published release is
> always a good practice, we really spend lot of time testing and
> debugging to offer best soft.

So, the answer is NO.

And try to use the last release keepalived.

Thanks for Alexandre Cassen.